# How do I automatically populate sheet 3 with a row of data from sheet 2 if a date in a column in sheet 1 is also in a column in sheet 2?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook with 2 sheets thus far. 1 sheet denotes a date in a column with other data in the adjacent columns that is not relevant here. In sheet 2 there is also a date in a column and then adjacent 10 adjacent columns have a bunch of data as well. I want to make a new table (sheet 3) that will populate if and only if the date in sheet 1 is also in sheet 2 and will return JUST the data from the entire row of the matching date in sheet 2.  The real pain in the butt is that sometimes there are multiple rows that share the same date in sheet 2.

Example, in sheet 1 I have 2/19/2019 in B4. Sheet 2 also has 2/19/2019 in it with a bunch of data to the right of it for the production of that day. In sheet 3 I would like to automatically return the entire row from sheet 2. Is this possible? I'm getting a headache :)

I've tried using COUNTIF and also MATCH but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it check the entire column(s) for matching dates.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would:

- In 'Sheet 1' and 'Sheet 2', make sure all dates are in column 'A'.
- Create 'Sheet 3' and list all possible dates down column 'A'.

In column 'B' of 'Sheet 3', write the following formula....

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!$A:$A,$A1,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A,$A1)>0,VLOOKUP($A1,'Sheet 2'!$A:$Z,#COLUMN NUMBER#,0),"")
```

You will need to replace **#COLUMN NUMBER#** with the column number you wish to return from 'Sheet 2'.  Entering '1' (without quotations) will return column 'A', '2' will return column 'B' etc...

Repeat this across as many columns as you require in 'Sheet 3'.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to do with just formulae. What Dominic has suggested would solve the issue for the first instance. Although, I believe it may have some issues with the comment mentioning "multiple rows that share the same date in sheet 2".
I think the formulae would only return the first row that matches the criteria.

I see that there is no VBA tag, but the only answer I could come up with was a VBA script to get around these clauses.
It also needs a helper column on "Sheet2" to identify that a row has already been checked, which I have set as Column H (8th column) in my test spreadsheet.

In case this is useful to you, please find it below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Worksheet_activate()
Dim b, c, d, x As Integer
Dim a, ab, ac As Worksheet

'Names of the spreadsheets need to be in the speech marks.
Set a = Worksheets("Sheet1")    'Sheet to be compared.
Set ab = Worksheets("Sheet2")   'Sheet to look through and copy from.
Set ac = Worksheets("Sheet3")   ' Sheet to be pasted into.

b = a.Cells(a.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row            'Bottom date in column A of "Sheet1"
c = ab.Cells(ab.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row          'Bottom date in column A of "Sheet2"
d = ac.Cells(ac.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1      'Next empty space in column A of "Sheet3"
e = 8                                                   'Number value for the helper column. Set as 8 for column H.
x = 2

Do Until x > c
    'Helper column placed in column H.
    If ab.Cells(x, e) = "" Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(a.Range("A2:A" & b), ab.Range("A" & x)) >= 1 Then
            ab.Rows(x).Copy
            ac.Range("A" & d).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            d = ac.Cells(ac.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
    End If
    'Text added to helper column
    ab.Cells(x, e) = "Yes"
    x = x + 1
Loop
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ac.Range("A" & d).Select
End Sub
```

The following information would need to be edited to accommodate your spreadsheet:

- Change the names of the 3 spreadsheets in the speech marks e.g. Set a = Worksheets(" Here ")
- Change the value of e to the number of the column the helper column is in i.e. =COLUMN()

It would then need to be added to the sheet by right-clicking the sheet the data is copied into and selecting "View Code" before pasting into the window that opens up.
The code runs when the tab is opened, so the tab may need to be toggled to update it in some situations.